# Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, eu estou a criar um media player no Visual Studio, e a única maneira que encontrei de por o video a dar foi através do componente do Windows Media Player. Encontrei também que para retirar as barras onde se encontra o play/pause, etc. do windos media player vai-se ás propriedades e onde esta "uniMode- Full" mete-se «none» e a barra desaparece no design. Quando meto iniciar o aplicativo, a barra volta a aparecer. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como poderei resolver isto?

Comment: Poderia postar seu código? Não tem nenhum lugar do código que você altera esse componente?

Comment: Sim a única propriedade que alterei até ao momento foi o unimode para none